# Converting lat/lon strings to tuple

Tags: python, type-conversion, tuples

I want to create a function that converts lat/lon string into tuples. 
This is what I have tried but it is giving me an error "could not convert string to float".

Thanks for your help.

```
def convert(d):
    d.replace(" ", "")
    return [tuple(map(float,coords.split(','))) for coords in d.split()]

convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
```

Output:
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: `d.replace(" ", "")` returns a new string, just do: `d = d.replace(" ", "")`.

Comment: can you give an example of `d`?

Comment: @MasonCaiby you can see and example of in the call `convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")`

Comment: `def convert(d):    return tuple(map(float,d.split(','))) # (-122.4194, 37.7749)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` like this: [[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)]

```py
>>> import ast
>>>
>>> d = "-122.4194, 37.7749"
>>> print(ast.literal_eval(d))
(-122.4194, 37.7749)
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(d))
<class 'tuple'>
```

**This method will only work if you expect the input to *look like* a tuple like is given in your example** `convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")`

So for your code if you want to use `convert(d)`

```py
import ast

def convert(d):
    return ast.literal_eval(d)

convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
```

Result:

```py
>>> x = convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
>>> type(x)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> x
(-122.4194, 37.7749)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is that you are splitting `d` on whitespace with `d.split()` in your list comprehension. For your example input this is unnecessary. Just split on the comma:

```
def convert(d):
    d.replace(" ", "")
    return tuple(map(float,d.split(',')))

coords = convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
print(coords)
```

Since `float()` ignores whitespace anyway, you don't need to call `d.replace()`:

```
def convert(d):
    return tuple(map(float,d.split(',')))

coords = convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
print(coords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this? This removes the need to replace the `' '` with `''` and also simplifies the work you were doing in your function. It also doesn't require any extra packages. Actually, you `float()` will strip the leading space from the second point in your tuple.

```
def convert(d):
    return tuple(map(float,d.split(',')))

convert("-122.4194, 37.7749")
```

Note that in cases when you do want to remove whitespace from the beginning and ending of a string, you can use `strip()` instead of `replace(' ', '')`.